# When I get the daily bonus, why don't the items show up in the journal?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I spin the first PokéStop of the day, a bunch of items come out. When I check the journal, it only shows 3 or 4.  Why doesn't it show all the items in the journal?

Answer (score 7):

> ## This bug has been fixed.

After getting the PokéStop, you'll notice some of the items along the side of the screen have a yellow background. Those are the bonus items.   I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but the journal does not list the bonus items.

[image]
[image]