# Colored background on pokestop items?

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]

Why are some pokestop items in different back ground colors?  These are not my first pokestop of the day and they have both yellow and blue background items.

Comment: @Vemonus half duplicate, the yellow items are only briefly discussed in the comments. The linked question is also Gym specific. This asks for Pokestops too.

Comment: There's also [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/292314/162442) and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/311715/162442), then.

Comment: However, the confusion that raised this question is specifically the different colored backgrounds on the gym disc spins. "These are not my first pokestop[s] of the day and they have both yellow and blue background items" indicates that they understand a yellow background on the pokestop item represents the first of the day bonus, but they are asking about the colors on the items received from the gyms.

Comment: @Vemonus I still don't see the problem with this question... What harm is done by consolidating information so it's easier to find, rather than doing 2 separate searches?

Comment: @Supergoat21 I don't see any purpose in having a third question that merely restates the information given more in depth in two previous, well-written Q&As.

Answer (score 5):

Ok after some searching I've found this out:

- Yellow items are bonus items given for your first Pokestop of the day.
- Yellow items are also given at Gyms if you have a Gym badge
- Blue/Red/Presumably yellow for Instinct? items are given at Gyms when you spin a disc on a Gym that your team

In your example the Pokestop must have been your first of the day, hence yellow items. The other two are gyms controlled by your team, both of which you have a gym badge for, so you got yellow and blue items.

[This guy](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/75606036) seems to confirm this.

[Niantic](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=getting-started&f=gather-items-at-pokestops-and-gyms) confirm the Gym aspect.